# Understanding user login flow for AIX

Tags: unix, aix

I know that when a user logs into the AIX server, the system files csh.cshrc and csh.login are called. /etc/passwd also come into the picture. Can someone point me to a document that clearly explains the log in flow for a AIX machine. I mean which files are called and in what order?

Comment: This can help http://aix4admins.blogspot.nl/2012/06/user-login-process-login-process.html Also, this fits better in [sf].

Comment: This question is about Unix, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This is not really AIX specific but shell specific.  What csh does is not the same as what ksh does.  If you install bash, it does something different still.

IBM pubs for 6.1 start [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp).  Other versions of pubs have a similar path.  In your case, do a search for: login csh

`man csh` has information about your question as well.

Hope this helps.